# Server sent event stream not triggering events

Tags: http, rust, server-sent-events

I'm trying have a client create an event stream and print the server sent events in a list using this script:

```js
const eventSrc = new EventSource("game");

//Create list item for each event message
eventSrc.addEventListener( "ping", (event) => {
const newElement = document.createElement("li");
const eventList = document.getElementById("list");

newElement.textContent = `message: ${event.data}`;
eventList.appendChild(newElement);
            
eventSrc.close();
});
```

After sending the request for the event stream it doesn't trigger any events.
It does receive the data, but the response is interpreted as plain text.
After closing the connection sever-side it get this fron the debug panel:
[firefox developer panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEn1H.png)

The response header should be set correctly. Here's what i get from curl:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
{"content-type": "text/event-stream; charset=utf-8", "cache-control": "no-cache"}
```

I checked the server code and it is flushing the output after each message.
Here's the server code:

```rust
    match req.headers().get("accept"){
        Some(v) => {
            if v == "text/event-stream" {
                let message = "event: ping\ndata: connection established!\n\n";
                let res = Response::builder()
                    .status(StatusCode::OK)
                    .header("Content-Type", "text/event-stream; charset=utf-8")
                    .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                    .body(message.to_string()).unwrap();

                send_response(&mut stream, res).unwrap(); //Writes the initial response header and flushes down TCPStream
                for _ in 1..10 {
                    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(1));
                    stream.write_all(message.as_bytes()).unwrap();
                    match stream.flush() { Ok(_) => {println!("sent!")}, Err(_) => println!("error!") }; //Writes the message to the TCPStream
                }
            }
                else {
                send_response(&mut stream, get_page(req.uri().path())).unwrap();
            }
        },
        None => {}
    };
```

Edit:
For some added Context, the stream opject is just a TcpStream from the std::net crate.

The send_response() function just takes a Request from the http::Request and formats it to a string and writes to the stream:

```
fn send_response(stream: &mut TcpStream, res: Response<String>) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let (header, body) = res.into_parts(); 
    let response = format!("{:?} {:?}\n{:?}\r\n\r\n{body}", header.version, header.status, header.headers);
    return stream.write_all(response.as_bytes())
}
```

I've run the program with curl as the client and i do get the stream data with the expected header and i do get the data in one second intervals.
Heres the full terminal output:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:7878...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 7878 (#0)
> GET /game HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:7878
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: text/event-stream
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200
< {"content-type": "text/event-stream; charset=utf-8", "cache-control": "no-cache"}
* no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end
< 
event: ping
data: connection established!

event: ping
data: connection established!

event: ping
data: connection established!

event: ping
data: connection established!

event: ping
data: connection established!

event: ping
data: connection established!

event: ping
data: connection established!

event: ping
data: connection established!

event: ping
data: connection established!

event: ping
data: connection established!

* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: What crate are you using (there are like a dozen of different web server crates for Rust)? What is the implementation of `send_response()`?

Comment: This doesn't quite explain why nothing happens at all, but you're also closing your `EventSource` as soon as you receive the first event.

Comment: @at54321 I'm just using the the std::net for sending and reciveing data. The stream is just a TcpStream. I'll update the question with the details.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the issue was with how I was printing the responses.
I was using the Display methods to print out the headers when i should of just been printing the strings plainly.

I changed the send_response function to this:

```rust
fn send_response(stream: &mut TcpStream, res: Response<String>) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let (header, body) = res.into_parts(); 
    let mut headers_str = String::new();
    for (key, value) in header.headers.iter() {
        headers_str.push_str(&format!("{}: {}\r\n", key.as_str(), value.to_str().unwrap()));
    }
    let response = format!("{:?} {:?}\r\n{}\r\n\r\n{body}", header.version, header.status, headers_str);
    return stream.write_all(response.as_bytes())
}
```

Now the response header is being properly read  by the browser and it's all working now.